# Linux mouse freezes after suspend

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, mouse, touchpad

Today I finally decided to switch from Windows to Ubuntu.
I fully install Ubuntu, but everytime my notebook goes in sleepmode and wakes up my mouse will not work anymore. When I do a reboot it works fine until I let it sleep (even if it's for 10sec).

So I tried switching to Mint, however even with Mint I had the same problem. I have been trying to fix it all day without success.

Notebook:
Asus laptop

On a similar forum post this was the fix:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all
```

However this did not work for me.

Comment: I'm having this problem with left mouse button dies after sleep. None of the answers here worked for me.  Did any for you?

Comment: i have Ubuntu 22 version and i have same problem...

Comment: I solved this similar problem after suffering it daily for more than 2 years: https://askubuntu.com/a/1493498/48214

Answer (score 17):

I can confirm a similar issue with my touchpad on HP ProBook 450 G6 with Ubuntu 18.04, it was very laggy after suspend.

What worked for me:
create `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/touchpad`:

```
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in
  post)
    /sbin/rmmod i2c_hid && /sbin/modprobe i2c_hid 
  ;;
esac
```

make file executable `chmod +x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/touchpad`
and test (suspend computer and wake-up again)

Comment: Just got an HP Probook 440 G6 and installed Xubuntu 18.04, and had the same issue. Blindly followed these instructions with zero attempt at understanding why :) Works great now! +1

Comment: FWIW I needed to change my command to the following

`/sbin/rmmod rmi_smbus && /sbin/modprobe rmi_smbus` 

Using a Thinkpad T440s

Comment: Could the OP please make this the approved solution?. Had this issue on a Lenovo Yoga S1 and T470 and this solution provided a fix for both machines.

Answer (score 15):

This issue goes back at least a couple of years. It's a problem for a lot of Asus owners, but it's not entirely specific to Asus devices. Also, it's not Debian-specific — though in your case both Ubuntu and Mint have Debian roots.

It's a tricky one because it seems everyone's mileage varies with each proposed solution (and they all have slight hardware variances). There are countless threads trying to solve it.

**Notable bug threads on Launchpad (depending on your Asus model):**

- [Elantech touchpad stops working after suspend](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1490130)
- [FocalTech touchpad stops working after suspend](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1504445)

**Applicable bug thread on Kernel.org:**

- [ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad dies after resume from suspend](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=107971)

Assuming you don't want to patch your kernel, there are a couple potential runtime solutions you can try.

*(Note: You can open a terminal with `Ctrl+Alt+T`)*

**Disable/Enable the Mouse Driver:**

You can remove and then re-insert your mouse driver module with the following commands:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

**Disable/Enable via Xinput:**

Find your trackpad ID with the following command:

```
xinput --list
```

Once you have your device ID—I'll call it `12` for this example—try disabling and enabling the device with:

```
xinput --disable 12
xinput --enable 12
```

*(Replace `12` with your trackpad's device ID)*

**Alternative:**

As an aside, you may want to try hibernating instead of suspending. Supposedly the problems aren't as prevalent with hibernation.

Comment: Disable/Enable the Mouse Driver worked for me (`sudo modprobe -r psmouse` / `sudo modprobe psmouse`).
Hint: I added this to my `~/.gnomerc` so it is called every time I log in.

Comment: On ubuntu.18.04, `xinput --disable 12` and `xinput --enable 12` worked for me.

Comment: UPDATE #1: this issue happened again and this time the two `xinput` commands I mentioned in my previous comment did NOT work. UPDATE #2: To fix the issue I mentioned in UPDATE #1, I suspended my computer, then un-suspended it, and then  tried the two `xinput` commands again and it worked.  Why would `xinput` not work during UPDATE #1?

Comment: Dell Latitiude. `xinput --disbale 11` and `xinput --enable 11` worked for me. Ubuntu 16.04!
Thanks a lot.Was searching for this answer for almost a week

Comment: I really appreciated this answer, but unfortunately none of these steps fixed my scroll wheel issue. Would you mind taking a look? I'd appreciate it! https://askubuntu.com/q/1358360/48214

Answer (score 3):

What I do to restart the touchpad driver is similar to what Tom Hale suggested. I created a script called touch_restart.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
$sudo rmmod i2c_hid && $sudo modprobe i2c_hid
```

and then you can always execute it quickly with:
    echo "su_pass"|sudo -S sh touch_restart.sh

Also, it seems that disabling "Disable touchpad when typing" increases the periods between each touchpad freeze (it freezes very often on my Asus laptop).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I couldn't get this working. I wonder if you might know the answer to this: https://askubuntu.com/q/1358360/48214 I appreciate you taking a look.

Answer (score 1):

On Lenovo v145 15AST Ubuntu 20.04 with Logitech Bluetooth mouse, I created script

```
/lib/systemd/system-sleep/KickPebbleMouse.sh
```

Which uses `rfkill`

```
#!/bin/sh
# put this in /lib/systemd/system-sleep/
# kick the bluetooth because mouse is doesn't work after suspend.

case $1 in
    post)
        sleep 1
        btid=`rfkill --output ID,DEVICE| grep hci | sed -n -E 's/^ //;1p' | cut -d" " -f1`
        rfkill block ${btid}
        sleep 2
        rfkill unblock ${btid}
    ;;
esac
```

edit1: ---
Added sed into pipline to remove leading space when ID's are less than 2 digits (ie <10)

edit2: ---
Since the upgrade of the kernel (which I installed 11-Nov-2020) also included an update of the firmware, this solved the *Stuck mouse after suspend* problem, But I still can't use the wifi that is builtin to the same chip. [rtl8821ce]

See the Kernel and Firmware version change below.

Previous kernel boot:

```
$ journalctl -b -3 |grep -i -e "Linux version \| bluetooth.* version"
Nov 04 10:24:52 lenou2004 kernel: Linux version 5.4.0-52-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-060) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)) #57-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 10:57:00 UTC 2020 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-52.57-generic 5.4.65)
Nov 04 10:24:53 lenou2004 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
Nov 04 10:24:54 lenou2004 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x826ca99e
```

Newer kernel boot:

```
$ journalctl -b -2 |grep -i -e "Linux version \| bluetooth.* version"
Nov 11 11:38:06 lenou2004 kernel: Linux version 5.4.0-53-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-007) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)) #59-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 21 09:38:44 UTC 2020 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-53.59-generic 5.4.65)
Nov 11 11:38:08 lenou2004 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
Nov 11 11:38:08 lenou2004 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x829a21e4
Nov 11 11:44:32 lenou2004 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
Nov 11 11:44:32 lenou2004 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x829a21e4
```

edit3 ---
The original problem has returned, I haven't kept track when it first occurred. Current Kernel/firmware:

```
journalctl -b  |grep -i -e "Linux version \| bluetooth.* version"
Dec 12 11:36:25 lenou2004 kernel: Linux version 5.4.0-58-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-004) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)) #64-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 9 08:16:25 UTC 2020 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-58.64-generic 5.4.73)
Dec 12 11:36:27 lenou2004 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
Dec 12 11:36:27 lenou2004 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x829a21e4
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I couldn't get this working. I wonder if you might know the answer to this: https://askubuntu.com/q/1358360/48214 I appreciate you taking a look.

Comment: The bluetooth began working again after system wake-up from sleep after a few kernel upgrades, so I disabled my script, and since about 6 weeks ago the Wifi portion of that chip started working after an upgrade to Linux 5.11.0 (still Ubuntu but now 20.04.3).

Answer (score 0):

I call this script `mouse-reset`. It removes and then `modprobe`s a list of mouse-related modules:

```
#!/bin/bash

modules=(psmouse hid_multitouch elan_i2c)

for mod in "${modules[@]}"; do
    sudo rmmod "$mod" 2> /dev/null
    sudo modprobe -v "$mod" 2> /dev/null
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I couldn't get this working. I wonder if you might know the answer to this: https://askubuntu.com/q/1358360/48214

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu gnome tweaks has a feature called disable touchpad while typing. Some times disabling that feature worked for me. I currently use ubuntu 18.04

Tweaks -> keyboard & Mouse -> touchpad -> disable while typing

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/eeijll/mouse_got_stucked_in_ubuntu_1804_please_help/fbu8m46/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf

Commands :-

uname -a ------->>> check the kernel version

sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 ------>>> update the kernel to Kernel 5.0.0-37-generic

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable "Two-finger Scrolling" under Settings > Mouse & Touchpad

Comment: Thanks for your answer; just curious, did you have that problem before, and your answer worked, or is it an educated guess?

Comment: Worked for me. should work for you too, let me know if not.