# Scroll wheel doesn't work for wireless mouse after system wakes up

Tags: mouse, suspend, hibernate

I have a new Lenovo ThinkPad E15 that came with Windows 10 installed. I added Ubuntu 20.04 as an option (dual-boot).

Whenever the laptop sleeps (goes into a "suspend" or "hibernate" state) and then later I wake it up, the Logitech wireless mouse scroll wheel doesn't work.  ("Logitech MK270 Wireless Keyboard and Mouse Combo", but the only thing that doesn't work is the scroll wheel.)

I then unplug its USB-A dongle and replug it (sometimes I need to do this twice), and then the mouse wheel works again.

I don't want to need to touch the USB plug at all. It should just always work. How can I fix this?

(I already tried the answers at [Linux mouse freezes after suspend](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309247/linux-mouse-freezes-after-suspend)).

Comment: This is still driving me crazy every day. See also https://askubuntu.com/q/1358360/48214

Comment: Use windows....